# Have been scanning for NaN and getting lost

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, nan

I am defining a function that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the largest of them.

Here is my code:

```
var instructions = alert("Choose a set of numbers to input for the computer to determine which value is the largest");

var inputOne = prompt("Please input your first desired value");
var inputTwo = prompt("Please input your second desired value");

// THIS ARRAY STORES THE VALUES OF inputOne && inputTwo
var maxInput = Math.max([inputOne, inputTwo]);

var inputThree = prompt("Please input your third desired value");

// THIS WILL COMPARE BETWEEN THE inputThree && THE MAX INPUT OF THE USERS FIRST TWO CHOICES
var maxNumber = Math.max(maxInput, inputThree);


//validate if inputs are numbers and not letters
// isNaN()

    var compare = function (maxNumber, inputThree) {

    if (inputThree === maxNumber) {
        return alert("The result is the same!");

    } else if (inputThree != maxNumber) {
                return alert(maxNumber + " " + "is the larger value!");

    }
}
compare(maxNumber, inputThree);
```

Now I'm getting a result of "NaN is the larger value!" and it's driving me crazy! I tried running console.log to see where I'm getting NaN but that didn't work at all. All that did was log NaN to the console.

I also tried taking the parameters out of Math.max( ) however was just getting:
"-infinity is the larger value!"

Can someone at least give me a hint as to why this is happening? Or explain to me further what is going on.

Comment: `Math.max()` does not take an array as argument. Compare `Math.max([1, 2])` with `Math.max(1, 2)`.

Comment: Also, in the `else if` in the `compare` function, use `!==` instead of `!=` to force numeric values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.max([inputOne, inputTwo])` should be `Math.max(inputOne, inputTwo)`

Why don't you just get the largest of all of them with just

```
var maxNumber = Math.Max(inputOne, inputTwo, inputThree);
```

Comment: Oh wow, of course, I was trying to do that before but idk what I was doing. Now that I'm looking at it today it all makes sense. I was definitely making it more complicated than it needed to be, can you tell I'm new to this? Haha, anyway thank you very much Barmar!!

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
var inputThree = prompt("Please input your third desired value");
```

*inputThree* is a String (i.e. its value has a Type of [*String*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4)), always. And here:

```
var maxNumber = Math.max(maxInput, inputThree);
```

*maxNumber* is a Number, always (because that's what [*Math.max*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.11) returns, even though the arguments are Strings). So:

```
inputThree === maxNumber
```

is always false, because a *Number* is never equal to a *String* (see the [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)). So either convert *inputThree* to a Number, e.g.

```
+inputThree === maxNumber
```

or use `==`.

```
inputThree == maxNumber
```